# Django Admin not reloading data after updated mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-admin

I have a django admin section which I use to create new "section" items and add them into a section table in mysql.  In the admin section I have a typed choice field that displays all of the previously made "sections" which are taken from a table in Mysql. Adding new sections works fine except for the fact that when I add a section, if I immediately want to add another the new section which was just added does not appear in the typed choice field choices. But, if I restart the server it does. Does anyone know how to do this without restarting the server?

Here is my current form code.

```
mysql_user = 'root'
mysql_password = ''
mysql_database = 'CareerServices'
mysql_host = '127.0.0.1'

def mysql_cursor(connection):
    return connection.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)

def mysql_con():
    con = mdb.connect(mysql_host, mysql_user, mysql_password, mysql_database)
    return con


class NewMainSectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    c = mysql_con()
    cr = mysql_cursor(c)
    cr.execute("select SectionTitle from CareerServicesSections where SectionLevel order by SectionTitle")
    rows = cr.fetchall()
    ch = [('','None')]
    for row in rows:
        try:
            ch.append( (row['SectionTitle'], row['SectionTitle'] ) )
        except:
            print traceback.print_exc() 
    SectionTitle = forms.CharField(label="New Section Title", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'90'}));
    SectionAbove = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=ch, label='Section Above',required=False)
```

Thanks and much appreciated.

Comment: why you not using models?

Comment: I am using models. This form automatically creates a model object and adds it to the correct table. The models are working fine.